# career advice embedded software development?

Tags: embedded, programming

I am a fresh BSC electrical engineering graduate and very much interested in the   software side. and i have a couple of questions for people who have some know how of embedded software development.

1. What an embedded software development job is like? I mean how much software work and hardware work. can it be for some one who likes software more than hardware?
2. Can embedded software developers develop mobile application/software like android/iphone/ipad development sort of thing? (without cs degree)
3. Finally if i want to do masters what degree will suit me? embedded systems engineering or embedded computing or some other?
4. Are there any other options for a BSC electrical programming enthusiast other than embedded software development?

Comment: I"m an ex-EE who now only works at software. Keep learning and pushing to find work that interests you.

Comment: I'm an ex(?)-CS man who loves hardware. Same advice. The borderline between SE and EE is a nice niche to fill: not many guys from either side have a reasonable grasp of the other side. In my country there is still a shortage of both EE and CS, so anyone who is reasonably skilled is hired. At the school I work for be consider iPhone & Android to be mainstream CS work, not specifically for embedded CS studentents.

Comment: @kenny Thanks for your inspiring comments, really needed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I have been a consultant/contract engineer for the last 30 years or so specializing in embedded systems.  I do both hardware and software design, but my experience is that except for the smallest companies, this is usually split up and there are separate firmware engineers and hardware engineers.

Because of the nature of embedded systems work, even firmware engineers need to have a basic grasp of electronics, and be able to read schematics and use an oscilloscope, logic analyzer, and digital multimeter and maybe a signal generator or arbitrary waveform generator.  In addition  one needs to be able to read and understand technical datasheets, some of which run into three or four hundred pages for a complex microcontroller with lots of embedded peripherals.

So in addition to debugging your code, you will be spending a lot of time probing a circuit looking at signals.

At the beginning of a project, even if you are not directly involved in the actual hardware design, you may be asked to participate in the design of the circuit, offering suggestions where things might be changed to make the firmware easier to manage.

When I am functioning as a hardware engineer, I design circuits (digital or mixed analog/digital), enter the schematic into a schematic capture program, lay out the PCB (printed circuit board), and develop the BOM (bill of materials).  When the boards come back, check out the power supplies are all working (today's circuits often require three or more different voltages or rails).  Then I write firmware routines to check out all of the peripherals individually.

2) It is certainly possible to develop mobile software (or any software without a CS degree), but you will develop better and more maintainable software after having some formal education in the subject.  See next answer for more on this.

3) I got my BSEE actually a few years before the first microprocessor was invented.  After graduating, I was doing logic design for a large telephone company research lab.  It soon became apparent to me that a lot or most of the hardware I was designing would be done by computers some day.  So I went back and got an MSCS.

That turned out to be one of the best decisions I ever made.  Having the combination of both hardware and software degrees has gotten me one job after another.

The original 8-bit micros couldn't do all that much and the operating systems they ran under (if any) were quite primitive.  But as the industry switched first to 16-bit and then 32-bit microcontrollers, the complexity of the firmware has grown such that the two or three dollar micro today has roughly the same computing power as a mainframe 40 years ago.

I still work a lot with 8-bit micrcontrollers in addition to the larger ones.  You will probably be working almost exclusively with 32-bit microcontrollers.  So having a firm grounding in CS will be necessary.

Embedded systems engineering and embedded computing degrees didn't exist when I went to school, which is why I went for the traditional CS degree.  The embedded system degrees are good in that you will be having lots of labs where you actually work on the little buggers.  But if you pick one of the embedded degrees, make sure you are getting a good general CS curriculum too.

4) I can't think of any right now but may someone else can come up with some.

Comment: really appreciate the time you put in the post.Well my priority choice was to persue MSCS but i found that to be eligible for MSCS one needs to have a BSCS degree or atleast must have studied core CS courses like operating systems,databases,compiler theory etc etc which i havent as BSc EE graduate. So i thought with embedded software side i would still have the software element.But interestingly, you mentioned that you did BSEE and then MSCS. It would really help if you can  comment on that, how did you manage to do MSCS after BSEE.

Comment: @AhmedWaqas Well, first of all this was 40 years ago.  I got my BSEE from a good university (Iowa State, where the [first electronic computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atanasoff%E2%80%93Berry_Computer) was invented).  However I only had a couple of programming classes during my undergraduate work -- in FORTRAN IV no less!  When I applied to graduate school at another university, I got in with the understanding I would have to take several undergraduate courses first, which were prerequisites for the graduate courses I would be taking.  So it took longer than normal to complete my degree.